# iOS Keyboard in Swift is too wide and tall when loading from XIB file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xib

I'm building a keyboard using Swift (XCode 6 with iOS 8.3 SDK) and when I load the xib, the keyboard is about 1000 pixels too wide and tall. I've, in the freeform xib file, put all my keys in a UIView and set the UIViews constraints to superview top, bottom, left and right.

[image]

As you can see, the result is annoying. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

var BlurBoardView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadInterface()
}

func loadInterface() {
    //load the nib file
    var blurboardNib = UINib(nibName: "BlurBoardView", bundle: nil)
    // initiate the view
    BlurBoardView = blurboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    // add the interface to the main view
    view.addSubview(BlurBoardView)
    // copy the background color
    view.backgroundColor = BlurBoardView.backgroundColor

    let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
    blur.frame = view.frame
    view.addSubview(blur)
}

@IBAction func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject?) {

    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let title = button.titleForState(.Normal)
    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as! UITextDocumentProxy

    switch title as String!{
        case "<" :
            proxy.deleteBackward()
        case "RETURN" :
            proxy.insertText("\n")
        case " " :
            proxy.insertText(" ")
        case "CHG" :
            self.advanceToNextInputMode()
        default :
            proxy.insertText(title!)
    }
}

/*
override func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput) {
    // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
}

override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput) {
    // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

    var textColor: UIColor
    var proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as! UITextDocumentProxy
    if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark {
        textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    } else {
        textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    //self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitleColor(textColor, forState: .Normal)
}
*/
}
```

The keyboard, in it's precompiled xib looks like this:

[image]

You can also see the parent (of the keys) views constraints.

I'm mainly an Objective-C developer, so the code makes sense, but the issue might just be a huge SBE because of Swift, so sorry if it's ridiculously simple ;)

edit: The P key has a constraint to tie it 14 pixels to the left superview, and 0 pixels to the right (to the O key) which is how I know it's way too wide. Keyboard bottom constraint is to bottom of superview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you're using Autolayout and you're not setting constraints between your view and your BlurBoardView.

When ViewDidLoad is called, the view doesn't have its right frame. It's only when viewDidLayoutSubviews is called.

So set constraints between your view and your BlurBoardView in ViewDidLoad. Or put BlurBoardView.frame = *the frame your wish* in viewDidLayoutSubview.

Same thing for your blurView

Comment: Yup! Putting `BlurBoardView.frame = view.frame` into viewDidLayoutSubviews did the trick! Thanks.